# Python structured numpy array multiple sort

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hello all I have a list of delimiter separated strings:

```
lists=['1|Abra|23|43|0','2|Cadabra|15|18|0','3|Grabra|4|421|0','4|Lol|1|15|0']
```

I need to convert it to numpy array than sort it just like excel do first by Column 3, then by Column 2, and finaly by the last column
Ive tried this:

```
def man():
a = np.array(lists[0].split('|'))
for line in lists:
    temp = np.array(line.split('|'),)
    a=np.concatenate((a, temp))
a.sort(order=[0, 1])
man()
```

Of course no luck because it is wrong! Unfortunately im not strong in numpy arrays. Can somebody help me pls? :(

This works just perfect for me but here numpy builds array from file so to make it work i've write my list of strings to file than read it and convert to array

```
import numpy as np

# let numpy guess the type with dtype=None
my_data = np.genfromtxt('Selector/tmp.txt',delimiter='|', dtype=None, names ["Num", "Date", "Desc", "Rgh" ,"Prc", "Color", "Smb", "MType"])
my_data.sort(order=["Color","Prc", "Rgh"])

# save specifying required format (tab separated values)
print(my_data)
```

How to remain everything as is but change the conversion function to make it build the same array not from file but from list

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you want the end result to be. Can you put the target result of your example for clarity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be better solutions, but for a start I would sort the array once by each column in reverse order.

I assume you want to sort by column 3 and ties are resolved by column 2. Finally, remaining ties are resolved by the last column. Thus, you'd actually sort by the last column first, then by 2, then by 3.

Furthermore, you can easily convert the list to an array using a list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np

lists=['1|Abra|23|43|0','2|Cadabra|15|18|0','3|Grabra|4|421|0','4|Lol|1|15|0']

# convert to numpy array by splitting each row
a = np.array([l.split('|') for l in lists])

# specify columns to sort by, in order
sort_cols = [3, 2, -1]

# sort by columns in reverse order.
# This only works correctly if the sorting algorithm is stable.
for sc in sort_cols[::-1]:
    order = np.argsort(a[:, sc])
    a = a[order]

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension in order to split your strings and convert the integers to `int`. Then use a proper `dtype` to create your numpy array then use `np.sort()` function by passing the expected order:

```
>>> dtype = [('1st', int), ('2nd', '|S7'), ('3rd', int), ('4th', int), ('5th', int)]
>>> 
>>> a = np.array([tuple([int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in sub.split('|')]) for sub in delimit_strs], dtype=dtype)

>>> np.sort(a, axis=0, order=['3rd','2nd', '5th'])
array([(4, 'Lol', 1, 15, 0), (3, 'Grabra', 4, 421, 0),
       (2, 'Cadabra', 15, 18, 0), (1, 'Abra', 23, 43, 0)], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<i8'), ('2nd', 'S7'), ('3rd', '<i8'), ('4th', '<i8'), ('5th', '<i8')])
```

You can also do this in python which for shorter data sets in more optimized. You can simple use `sorted()` function by passing a proper key function.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted([[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in sub.split('|')]) for sub in delimit_strs], key=itemgetter(3, 2, 4))
```